# Parsing strings containing variable names in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, variables, casting

I'm currently writing an application in which I have a function as follows:

```
var a,b,c, algorithm: string
begin

a := some-operations-with-regular-expressions;
b := some-other-operation-with-regular-expressions;
c := just-similar-to-b-but-different;

algorithm := IniFile.ReadString('XML Info','AlgorithmExpression', ''); 
//algorithm is fetched like 'http://wwww.urlhere' + a + '/' + b + '/' + c
DoDownload (algorithm, true);
end;
```

Now what I expected was to have a, b & c automatically replaced with the values of the variables with the same name, but it appears that I'm so wrong. Is there any way to get the result of the algorithm variable composed of the strings between '' and the variable values?

Any suggestion (even if it calls for major redesigning) would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
sphynx

Comment: That is not how Delphi (or *any* programming language) works... `algorithm` is a string containing characters. That's it. Period.

Comment: This question is unclear... danger of being closed.

Comment: @Chris: I think that the OP has a string like `'Hello ' + name + '!'` (literally) and expects that `name` should be replaced by the contents of the string variable `name` automagically at runtime...

Comment: You expect that Delphi automatically parse the string expressing and replace appropriate variables with values which is not going to happen. You have to do it yourself. I advise you to change your algorithm expression stored in the INI file to contain "placeholders" so that you can easily replace them with actual values. For example, in your case replace `'http://wwww.urlhere' + a + '/' + b + '/' + c` with `http://wwww.urlhere%param1%/%param2%/%param3%`. Then do a `StringReplace` on `algorithm` variable so that it replaces %param#% with actual variable values.

Comment: @Andreas: yes, that was my initial impression. I'm not a programmer, so I sometimes just go with whatever crosses my mind.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I'm pretty sure you can do this in Perl, but you'd have to invoke `DoDownload` using the `eval` function.

Comment: @sphynx: I give you a +1 just because I think that the -1 is unfair. (And a question should not be downvoted just because it is very simple from the point of view of a programmer.)

Comment: @TMN: Yes, I should have written '<em>compiled</em> language', at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't understand what you are trying to do, but here goes a shot.

IniFile should contain something like this:

```
[XML Info]
AlgorithmExpression=http://wwww.urlhere[<a>]/[<b>]/[<c>]
```

and you could do something like this:

```
algorithm := IniFile.ReadString('XML Info','AlgorithmExpression', ''); 
algorithm := StringReplace(algorithm,'[<a>]',a,[]); 
algorithm := StringReplace(algorithm,'[<b>]',b,[]); 
algorithm := StringReplace(algorithm,'[<c>]',c,[]); 
DoDownload (algorithm, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, Christian, that's what I've been looking for. I'm not a professional, that's why I sometimes run into this kind of issues. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it now works like a charm :)

Answer (score 5):

If this is about formatting, Delphi also has the C style format command:

```
var
  output: String;
begin
  output := Format('http://%s/%s/%s', ['this', 'that', 'otherthing']);
  ShowMessage(output);
end;
```

Shows the message:

> http://this/that/otherthing